# Netbeans autocomplete unusably slow/nonfunctional in Netbeans 6.8 Latest

Tags: netbeans, autocomplete

I'm running a 2.5Ghz C2D with 4GB RAM, so there's no reason hardwre-wise why Netbeans should be peforming so poorly. Using the latest Netbeans release and grails plugin (installed via the plugin manager), automcomplete is either too slow to use or doesn't work at all.

If I'm within a class, and I attempt to auto-complete a field, it takes 3-4 seconds before being able to finish the field name.

If I'm in a class of the same package (like a unit test), I can't get any of the properties to appear on the object. Furthermore, it says "Scanning in progress" for a full 5-6 seconds before pulling up the method list.

Is there a way to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no solution to this. Hopefully 6.9 will handle grails better. Until then, IntelliJ offers the same or better functionality, and autocomplete actually works.